# Update certain variables using ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

currently working on the first implementation using ajax and I am struggeling.

I want to have certain values updated regularly on an already rendered page.

Controller

```
def something
  @var1 = 1
  @var2 = 2
  render :json => { :var1 = @var1, :var2 = @var2 }
end
```

The view currently looks like this:

```
:javascript
  var result = jQuery.getJSON( '/admin/tours/cc_dashboard_json', function(json) {
  var variables = JSON.parse(result);
  });

.container
  .row
    .span4
      %table
        %tr
          %h3= @var1 #used to just reload the page manually and here the
          %h3= @var2 #vars used to show up
```

Result of the json request:

```
{ "var1":1,"var2":2 }
```

What do I want with this?

I want var1 and var2 to be updated every x seconds with data from the ajax request. So i need js to request the data every x seconds and afterwards update the variables.

Comment: You can use [Window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to achieve this.

Comment: That works! Thanks. How can I make it load 1x when the page is loaded and then every x seconds?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6k485/1/

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to post an answer? So I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) for this purpose.

*According to MDN setInterval will:*

> Call a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call to that function.

Also you can run the function once the page loads then let the interval take over like this:

```
(function(){
   var start = function() {
     alert("Interval");
   };

   window.setInterval(start, 10000); //every 10 seconds

   start();
})();
```